# How can I update customer payment profile details in Authorize.NET (CIM)?

Tags: php, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I have a small problem with Authorize.NET SDK (CIM).
Currently i'm using PHP SDK and I need to update customer payment profile (bill to address, first name, last name), that is stored in CIM (i have customer profile id, payment profile id). But i have no credit card information (cvc2, card_number, exp_date).
Is it real?

Comment: Is what real? You need to specify what you're looking for as your question makes no sense.

Comment: I'm looking for solution to update customer payment profile without credit card information with Authorize.NET SDK.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can send masked credit card data to `updateCustomerPaymentProfileRequest` if you do not need to update it.

For the credit card number you would send `XXXX1111` where the last four digits must match last four digits of the the stored credit card. For the expiration date you would send `XXXX`.

You can use a call to `getCustomerPaymentProfileRequest` to obtain the proper masked credit card values.